# JavaScript file not working when i upload updated code to web hosting

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a small website - http://www.calvation.uk/MyWebsite/index.php

and down the bottom I have a box which should contain the time but for some reason the file isn't working. I have checked on my localhost and its working fine, so is it server side? is there a directory that I have to place JavaScript src in?

thanks in advance for any help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your file is not found, check your console.

`[Error] Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) (live_time_date.js, line 0)`

The folder you are looking for can't exist. If your index.php is located one folder down from the root and you are looking *two* folders down (../../Projects/Project_C/Javacakes/live_time_date.js) from the root, that folder can't even exist. Move the js file into a nice folder and link it like your CSS files.

Comment: Face palming right now...thanks" I had linked it in via another project... Thanks man!